# JavaFX setCellFactory if Enum != Admin

Tags: javafx

I have problem with restriction in my TableView.

```
    userRule.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().userRuleProperty());

    userRule.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(FXCollections
            .observableArrayList(RuleEnum.Admin.toString(), RuleEnum.Lider.toString())));
    userRule.setEditable(true);
        userRule.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
                AdminSQL sql = new AdminSQL();
                try {
                    sql.changeRule(userTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getUserLp(), event.getNewValue().toString());
                } catch (SQLException e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());e.printStackTrace();}  
        });
```

But in my Enum and in tableview colum i have 3 options: SuperAdmin, Admin and Lider. I dont want create combobox in rowcell if value=SuperAdmin.

Any idea ? :)

Comment: Create custom cells using a custom `cellFactory`. There is no existing code in the API that already does that for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fabian suggested in the comment, you can use a custom table cell which can handle this functionality. There is two ways:

```
userRule.setCellFactory(new ComboBoxTableCell<>(/* add the items here*/){
            @Override
            public void updateItem(RuleEnum item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if(empty){
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                }else if (RuleItem.SuperAdmin.equals(item)){
                    setEditable(false);
                }else {
                    setEditable(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

or

```
userRule.setCellFactory(new ComboBoxTableCell<>(/* add the items here*/){
        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            RuleEnum ruleEnum =  getTableRow().getItem().getEnum(); // insert your method here
            if(RuleEnum.SuperAdmin.equals(ruleEnum)){
                return;
            }
            super.startEdit();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It works in this way too

```
userRule.setEditable(true);
        userRule.setOnEditStart(e ->{
            if(e.getOldValue().equals(RuleEnum.SuperAdmin.toString())) {
                userRule.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(FXCollections
                        .observableArrayList(RuleEnum.Admin.toString(), RuleEnum.Lider.toString())));
                    userRule.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
                            AdminSQL sql = new AdminSQL();
                            try {
                                sql.changeRule(userTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getUserLp(), event.getNewValue().toString());
                            } catch (SQLException e1) {System.out.println(e1.getMessage());e1.printStackTrace();}   
                    });
            }
        });
```